# How to parse an invalid json file in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

So the json file I want to parse looks like this:

```
{
   "container_header_255_2013-12-31 16:00:45": {
  "fw_package_version": "255.255.255X255", 
  "start_timestamp": 1388534445, 
  "start_timestr": "2013-12-31 16:00:45", 
  "end_timestamp": 4294967295, 
  "end_timestr": "2106-02-06 22:28:15", 
  "length": 65535, 
  "product": "UNKNOWN", 
  "hw_version": "UNKNOWN"
   },
   "log_packet_debug_1388534445_2013-12-31 16:00:45": {
  "timestamp": 1388534445, 
  "timestr": "2013-12-31 16:00:45", 
  "log_level": "DBG", 
  "log_id": "0xC051", 
  "log_string": "DBG_STORAGE_LOG", 
  "file_name_line": "storage_data.c733", 
  "message": "Mark as Erasable: 231 238"
  },
```

sorry the indentation might be a  little off. but anyways all the examples I have seen online include lists and for some reason this one only contains dictionarys

Comment: import json
    v = json.loads(your_json_text)

However, I am guessing here and this ""message": "Mark as Erasable: 231 238" should be a list. Its not valid json and you will have to either write your own parser or format it as valid json:

    {
     ...
    "message": {"Mark as Erasable": [231, 238]}
    }

Comment: I thought that was the problem, I however did not create the json file so Ill just have to parse it manually.

Comment: Should be reopend as how to parse an invalid json file

Comment: I don't understand, what's invalid about your json text? Other than it not ending (which I'm guessing is an artifact of you snipping part of the text for the question, not an actual feature of your data), the text you've shown is valid.

Comment: @Blckknght Actually, I think this is the essence of the OP:s problem. This is a quite common problem with logfiles, for example.

Comment: @Krumelur: Ah, I see. That wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`splitstream`](https://github.com/evolvIQ/splitstream) module (disclaimer: I wrote it) for this (`pip install splitstream`). It has a parameter `startdepth` which is specifically designed to parse XML/JSON streams that has not yet been terminated or are "infinite" (such as log files).

```
from splitstream import splitfile
from StringIO import StringIO
import json

jsonfile = StringIO(""".....""") # your neverending JSON-sorta logfile
# Probably, you want something like this instead
#jsonfile = file("/var/log/my/log.json", "r")

# startdepth is the magic argument here: it starts splitting at depth = 1
for s in splitfile(jsonfile, format="json", startdepth=1):
  print "JSON",json.loads(s)
```

Which gives:

```
JSON {u'start_timestamp': 1388534445, u'hw_version': u'UNKNOWN', u'fw_package_version': u'255.255.255X255', u'product': u'UNKNOWN', u'end_timestr': u'2106-02-06 22:28:15', u'length': 65535, u'start_timestr': u'2013-12-31 16:00:45', u'end_timestamp': 4294967295}
JSON {u'file_name_line': u'storage_data.c733', u'log_level': u'DBG', u'log_id': u'0xC051', u'timestamp': 1388534445, u'timestr': u'2013-12-31 16:00:45', u'log_string': u'DBG_STORAGE_LOG', u'message': u'Mark as Erasable: 231 238'}
```